# Sort Array of Objects by Nested Key Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have `originalArray` that contains objects. How would I go around sorting arrays `inventory` array by key value `short`:

```
var originalArray = [
  {
    name: 'Store1',
    inventory: [
      { name: 'Oranges', qt: { short: 11, long: 3, med: 9 } },
      { name: 'Mango', qt: { short: 3, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Kiwi', qt: { short: 2, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Papaya', qt: { short: 8, long: 91, med: 3 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    inventory: [
      { name: 'Pizza', qt: { short: 31, long: 11, med: 23 } },
      { name: 'Burger', qt: { short: 1, long: 11, med: 23 } },
      { name: 'IceCream', qt: { short: 111, long: 11, med: 323 } }
    ]
  }
];
```

Desired output is:

```
var sorted = [
  {
    name: 'Store1',
    inventory: [
      { name: 'Kiwi', qt: { short: 2, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Mango', qt: { short: 3, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Papaya', qt: { short: 8, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Oranges', qt: { short: 11, long: 3, med: 9 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Sotre2',
    inventory: [
      { name: 'Burger', qt: { short: 1, long: 11, med: 23 } },
      { name: 'Pizza', qt: { short: 31, long: 11, med: 23 } },
      { name: 'IceCream', qt: { short: 111, long: 11, med: 323 } }
    ]
  }
];
```

I don't need anything but `inventory` array sorted by `short` value.

All the items of `inventory` array are sorted in dsc order. Performance is not an issue nor is language spec limit only limitation is that I can not use external libraries.

Is there a sane way of doing this or I need to pluck `inventory` into intermediary variable sort it there and create new array of objects with `inventory` sorted.

Comment: you could add what you have tried, and what is not working ...

Comment: try to implement something by yourself. It's just loop combined with `Array.sort`

Comment: It is really watered down array, I am already 5 layers deep into `map` and `reduce` to get that and I can not use intermediary variables nor helpers. Posting whole code would get me nowhere, and besides it was silly mistake on my end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
var originalArray = [
  {
    name: 'Store1',
    inventory: [
      { name: 'Oranges', qt: { short: 11, long: 3, med: 9 } },
      { name: 'Mango', qt: { short: 3, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Kiwi', qt: { short: 2, long: 91, med: 3 } },
      { name: 'Papaya', qt: { short: 8, long: 91, med: 3 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    inventory: [
      { name: 'Pizza', qt: { short: 31, long: 11, med: 23 } },
      { name: 'Burger', qt: { short: 1, long: 11, med: 23 } },
      { name: 'IceCream', qt: { short: 111, long: 11, med: 323 } }
    ]
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
  originalArray[i].inventory.sort(function(a, b) { return a.qt.short - b.qt.short; });
}

console.log(originalArray);
```

Comment: I did try that but I forgot to loop trough each array entry and use it that way. Silly mistake I guess I'm way just tiered.

Comment: If anyone wants to sort on string (name) property then change return statement to

`return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1`